# Unbounded series with finite Cesàro mean

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, cesaro-summable

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers with finite Cesàro mean i.e., $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\tfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i < \infty.$$
Prove or disprove
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{n}e^{-\tfrac{i^2}{n}}<\infty. $$

I think it is not true. But I could not find a counterexample. Now for a fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$, I was able to show $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{n}e^{-\tfrac{i^2}{n}}<\infty.$ For that I used the fact that since the Cesàro average is finite, $a_i \in o(i)$ and $\xi_n:=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i}{n}e^{-\tfrac{i^2}{n}}<\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, I posted a different question without much thinking. I was trying to find the answer for the above question.

Comment: The quantity $$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i\cdot\frac{e^{-i^2/n}}{n\xi_n} $$ is a weighted average of $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,$ as is $$ \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^\infty  a_i.$$ Without $\xi_n$ in the denominator, it is not. Unless $x_n=1$ for all $n,$ which you say is not true. But I'm not sure to what extent that helps, if at all. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, thank you for urging me to recheck my computation for $\xi_n$. It was worth it as $\xi_n$ turns out to be bounded. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $a_i\in o(i)$, so we can find $c>0$ such that $a_i\leq c i$. Thus it suffices to show $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \xi_n<\infty$. Let $f_n(x)=\tfrac{|x|}{n}e^{-x^2/n}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. It is easy to see, $$ \xi_n\leq \int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx. $$
Now 
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx &= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{n}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{2\pi(n/2)}}e^{-\tfrac{x^2}{2(n/2)}}\,dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{n}}\,\mathbb{E}(|Z_n|)\\
&=\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\tfrac{\pi}{n}}\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{\pi}}\sqrt{\tfrac{n}{2}}\\
&=\tfrac{1}{2}
\end{align}
where $Z_n\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\tfrac{n}{2})$. Thus $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\xi_n\leq\tfrac{1}{2}$ which proves the result.